# Hash Router back button with React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using HashRouter to setup my App like so:

```
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Routing = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
    <Route exact path ="/" component = {App} />
    <Route path ="/about" component = {About} />
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

It works great, but when I click a link to go to /about and then hit the back button nothing happens. How do I make it so my internet browser's back button will take me back to the previous page? The app is built using create-react-app if that makes a difference.

Comment: so `Router` is `HashRouter` component from `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry let me update

Comment: It should be working, check here https://codesandbox.io/s/oq80rrnl5

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: Have you tried Using `<Switch>` , import it from `react-router-dom` and then wrap your `<Route>` inside `<Switch>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)

> **Switch** is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In
>   contrast, every Route that matches the location renders inclusively.

This means that the way you are doing it all routes are being rendered because they match.

> If the URL is /about, then About, User, and NoMatch will all
>   render because they all match the path. This is by design, allowing us
>   to compose Routes into our apps in many ways, like sidebars and
>   breadcrumbs, bootstrap tabs, etc.
>
> Now, if we're at /about, Switch will start looking for a matching
>   Route. **Route path="/about"** will match and Switch will stop
>   looking for matches and render About

Your code should look like this

```
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Routing = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path ="/" component = {App} />
      <Route path ="/about" component = {About} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```